# SSH into device attached to another router

Tags: routing, router, ethernet, ssh, port-forwarding

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1031247/access-ssh-server-behind-two-routers)which looks kind of related, but I'm not sure as the answers are too confusing.

Basically, I want to SSH into my Raspberry Pi from my laptop. Eventually I want to have the Pi talking to the cloud (I want to install a personal VPN on it so I can be protected while traveling and just to learn).

[image]

Now, before you ask why I have two wireless routers on my home network, Router A is for a home office and due to the lead in the walls separating the office from the home (part of the office was once an X-Ray room), the wireless signal doe snot propagate. So it's mainly used as a firewall and to connect the office desktop to the web. Router B does the heavy lifting.

Now, I've set up the network as such (I don't know much about networking, but of the little I do, I managed to build this setup). However, in my reading, I understand that I need to forward a port, namely port 22 for the Pi. But on which end? Which router forwards the port? And is there a better way to do this in general? I'm open to suggestions.

Just for the record, the two routers are identical, [TRENDNet TEW-812DRU v1](https://www.trendnet.com/langen/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=100_TEW-812DRU)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. [su] was the correct place to ask your question. Also, network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking doesn't use network classes, please let them rest in peace.